# Kubernetes GKE 502 server error failed to pick backend when reloaded multiple times

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a vue js website deployed on Google Kubernetes Engine. Below is its deployment code:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: prod-e4o
  namespace: website
  labels:
    app: prod-e4o
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: prod-e4o
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: prod-e4o
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: gcr.io/*******
          name: app
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 500m
              ephemeral-storage: 1Gi
              memory: 0.75Gi
            requests:
              cpu: 500m
              ephemeral-storage: 1Gi
              memory: 0.75Gi
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3002
              name: http
          lifecycle:
            preStop:
              exec:
                command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "sleep 45" ]
          livenessProbe:
            initialDelaySeconds: 45
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 30
            tcpSocket:
              port: 3002
          readinessProbe:
            initialDelaySeconds: 45
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            tcpSocket:
              port: 3002
```

**Problem**

The issue is when I reload the website multiple times quickly, it suddenly starts displaying 502 server error page for about 5 to 20 seconds (sometimes the error is gone in 5 seconds, other times it takes 20 seconds to become available). Here's the exact error message.

```
Error: Server Error
The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

**Things I have tried so far:**

I have came across some questions with the same problems where it was suggested this issue might be due to resources. I have tried by increasing resources and making replicas 2 but the issue exist.

Some suggestions were that this is due to load balancer. I suspect that too because this is the log generated in Google cloud when this issue comes but I am not sure how this can be fixed:

```
{
  "insertId": "1ulcvwsf64b19x",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "remoteIp": "****",
    "statusDetails": "failed_to_pick_backend",
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.loadbalancing.type.LoadBalancerLogEntry"
  },
  "httpRequest": {
    "requestMethod": "GET",
    "requestUrl": "****",
    "requestSize": "278",
    "status": 502,
    "responseSize": "545",
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0",
    "remoteIp": "63.33.68.103",
    "referer": "www.wolframalpha.com",
    "latency": "0.018271s"
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "http_load_balancer",
    "labels": {
      "zone": "global",
      "url_map_name": "k8s2-um-97ve13di-website-website-c2lsezd7",
      "forwarding_rule_name": "k8s2-fs-97ve13di-website-website-c2lsezd7",
      "backend_service_name": "k8s1-d8188420-website-prod-e4o-3002-132d57a2",
      "target_proxy_name": "k8s2-ts-97ve13di-website-website-c2lsezd7",
      "project_id": "****"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-09-09T16:39:41.867486Z",
  "severity": "WARNING",
  "logName": "projects/****/logs/requests",
  "trace": "projects/****/traces/58bf40ba3fc95346005510c395c13f97",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-09-09T16:39:47.062198390Z",
  "spanId": "98c531a52c84ccca"
}
```

EDIT:
As asked in the comment, the result of command `kubectl describe <pod-name> -n <namespace>` is below:

```
Name:         prod-**-****-t4gz7
Namespace:    website
Priority:     0
Node:         gk3-prod-cluster-nap-zrypjsnr-e8f03002-qfsc/10.164.15.225
Start Time:   Thu, 08 Sep 2022 22:17:30 +0500
Labels:       app=prod-e4o
              pod-template-hash=785d68c9d6
Annotations:  kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt: 2022-09-08T17:17:30Z
              seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/pod: runtime/default
Status:       Running
IP:           10.121.0.172
IPs:
  IP:           10.121.0.172
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/prod-**-**
Containers:
  app:
    Container ID:   containerd://4da23c31271567c9237649e692a50001794eb16f61b005fb32d63413dd2cecd5
    Image:          ****
    Image ID:       ****
    Port:           3002/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Thu, 08 Sep 2022 22:18:24 +0500
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:                500m
      ephemeral-storage:  1Gi
      memory:             768Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:                500m
      ephemeral-storage:  1Gi
      memory:             768Mi
    Liveness:             tcp-socket :3002 delay=45s timeout=5s period=30s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:            tcp-socket :3002 delay=45s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:          <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-tgh9v (ro)
Readiness Gates:
  Type                                       Status
  cloud.google.com/load-balancer-neg-ready   True 
Conditions:
  Type                                       Status
  cloud.google.com/load-balancer-neg-ready   True 
  Initialized                                True 
  Ready                                      True 
  ContainersReady                            True 
  PodScheduled                               True 
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-tgh9v:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Guaranteed
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:                      <none>
```

Output for the command `kubectl describe ingress --namespace website`

```
Name:             website
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        website
Address:          34.102.204.15
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (10.121.0.75:8080)
Rules:
  Host                           Path  Backends
  ----                           ----  --------
  
  prod-url.com              
                                    prod-***:http (10.121.0.172:3002)
  www.prod-url.com          
                                    prod-***:http (10.121.0.172:3002)
  beta-url.com         
                                    beta-***:http (10.121.0.164:3002)

Annotations:                     ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: tls
                                 ingress.kubernetes.io/backends:
                                   {"k8s-be-31929--d81884208ac05b04":"HEALTHY","k8s1-d8188420-website-beta-cw-3001-74d92dad":"HEALTHY","k8s1-d8188420-website-beta-e4o-3002-0...
                                 ingress.kubernetes.io/forwarding-rule: k8s2-fr-97ve13di-website-website-c2lsezd7
                                 ingress.kubernetes.io/https-forwarding-rule: k8s2-fs-97ve13di-website-website-c2lsezd7
                                 ingress.kubernetes.io/https-target-proxy: k8s2-ts-97ve13di-website-website-c2lsezd7
                                 ingress.kubernetes.io/redirect-url-map: k8s2-rm-97ve13di-website-website-c2lsezd7
                                 ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-cert: capwell-tls,expert4office-tls
                                 ingress.kubernetes.io/static-ip: k8s2-fr-97ve13di-website-website-c2lsezd7
                                 ingress.kubernetes.io/target-proxy: k8s2-tp-97ve13di-website-website-c2lsezd7
                                 ingress.kubernetes.io/url-map: k8s2-um-97ve13di-website-website-c2lsezd7
                                 kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: true
                                 networking.gke.io/v1beta1.FrontendConfig: redirect-http-to-https
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                       From                     Message
  ----    ------  ----                      ----                     -------
  Normal  Sync    9m34s (x1024 over 6d14h)  loadbalancer-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

Output of the command `kubectl describe svc --namespace website`

```
Name:              prod-***
Namespace:         website
Labels:            app=prod-***
Annotations:       cloud.google.com/neg: {"ingress":true}
                   cloud.google.com/neg-status:
                     {"network_endpoint_groups":{"3002":"k8s1-d8188420-website-prod-***-3002-132d57a2"},"zones":["europe-west4-a","europe-west4-b"]}
Selector:          app=prod-***
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.121.128.147
IPs:               10.121.128.147
Port:              http  3002/TCP
TargetPort:        http/TCP
Endpoints:         10.121.0.172:3002
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Output of the command `kubectl describe ep -n website prod-e4o`

```
Name:         prod-e4o
Namespace:    website
Labels:       app=prod-e4o
Annotations:  <none>
Subsets:
  Addresses:          10.121.0.172
  NotReadyAddresses:  <none>
  Ports:
    Name  Port  Protocol
    ----  ----  --------
    http  3002  TCP

Events:  <none>
```

Comment: Could you execute the command `kubectl describe <pod-name> -n <namespace>` then update your question with the command results.

Comment: @JonB. updated the question with as you asked, please have a look.

Comment: To further check could you execute the following commands below, then update again your question with the command results. 

`kubectl describe ingress --namespace website`

`kubectl describe svc --namespace website`

`kubectl describe ep -n website prod-e4o`

Comment: @JonB. Updated the description with the additional commands that you mentioned in your comment. I have redacted some of the names to prevent any critical info from spilling. Thanks a lot for your response. Please have a look.

Comment: @UsamaBaig I have tested your deployment with the image `nginx:1.14.2` and did not face the issue you are describing, can you test with a different image in your cluster?

Comment: @GabrielRobledoAhumada I think this has to do something with load balancer and health check. I did some more searching on this issue and found some questions on SO where it was suggested to change health check from HTTP to TCP.
I have made this change in my health check and now I am monitoring the logs for any errors. Because refreshing the website again and again which previously broke it, is not replicating the issue for me. I will update here in either case. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the details that you have provided above I can see that from the logs generated there is a `"statusDetails": "failed_to_pick_backend"`, this could mean that there is unhealthy backend. You can configure the [correct firewall rules for health checks](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-checks#fw-rule).

As you have also mention that it is displaying the `502 server error page`, if this error 502 persist after you complete the load balancer configuration, it's likely that either:

- There's no [firewall rule configured to allow health checks](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/ext-https-lb-simple#firewall).
- The software on the backends isn't running.

You can refer also to this documentation on [Troubleshooting general connectivity issues](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/troubleshooting-ext-https-lbs#troubleshooting_general_connectivity_issues).